# Bootbox Element Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a function on my index file which is opening a bootbox modal. The idea is to place a litte contact form inside this modal window. The function is working correctly and the bootbox modal is opening, below my code:

jQuery

```
$('#form').click(function(){

$.get("modal.php", function(data,status){

           bootbox.dialog({
                   message: data,
                   title: "CONTACT US",

                });

    });
```

});

Problem is that i **cannot select any element inside this modal window**, for example i have a button inside this modal.php file

Html

```
<button id="cancelbutton" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Cancelar</button>
```

if i try to attach an event to this button nothing happens. What am i doing wrong here?

this is the code for the button event

```
$('#cancelbutton').on('click',function () {

                alert('Testing');
                console.log('Testing');

            });
```

I can target this element via css though:

```
#cancelbutton{background:#000;}
```

Comment: Attach jquery event to `canclebutton` in modal.php.

Comment: Does `modal.php` have any Javascript in it?

Comment: Please paste code for cancelbutton click event.

Comment: Hello, i tried also to put the cancelbutton event in modal.php file with no luck.

Comment: Hello Thauwa.Yes i was planning to use javascript in modal.php file, in this case the jquery form validation. I used this approach in the past and always worked. I have no idea why in this case i cannot select any elements on this modal on my index file.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. For future reference this was a Jquery version issue. Changing the version to 1.11.1 solved the problem.

Thanks